Intellij IDEA SplitEditorToolbar
Android Studio için bir Intellij IDEA eklentisi oluşturmaya çalışıyorum. Eklentiye bir SplitEditorToolbar eklemek ve düğmeler aracılığıyla ona eylemler eklemek istiyorum. Böyle bir şey elde etmeye çalışıyorum:
Bu fotoğraf Android Studio'ya aittir ve kırmızı ile işaretlenmiş alan benim istediğim şeydir.
eklenti eklemeye çalıştım ama bulamadım hiç bir yerde yardımcı olur musunuz

This site accepts English only. As for the plug-in development help, refer to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html.
